# Javascript Element Creation

Tags: javascript, forms, element, creation

I have the following code which creates a hidden input:

```
var hidden_id = document.createElement("INPUT");
            hidden_id.setAttribute("type","hidden");
            hidden_id.setAttribute("value","test");
            hidden_id.setAttribute("name","quick");
            hidden_id.setAttribute("id","quick");
```

This input is created into a form but the value wont pass from the form to a php page where I need to use it. I Know its not a problem with the form because I have other inputs in the form that are hard coded that pass values with no problem.

Any help appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: You never add the `hidden_id` element to the DOM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should append the input to the form:

```
var hidden_id = document.createElement("INPUT");
hidden_id.setAttribute("type","hidden");
hidden_id.setAttribute("value","test");
hidden_id.setAttribute("name","quick");
hidden_id.setAttribute("id","quick");

//Appending to the form...
document.forms[0].appendChild(hidden_id);
```